# Can I change background and font color of address bar at Chrome?

Tags: xubuntu, google-chrome, themes, chromium

I like dark themes for Chrome - but themes not affect at address bar. I also have dark theme at by Xubuntu.

[image: dark chromium at dark xubuntu linux, dark theme, dark gui]

Comment: I think this is hard-coded into Chrome itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Address bar at Chrome depends on system color theme. For switch to nice dark - Install [Dorian](http://killhellokitty.deviantart.com/art/Dorian-Theme-353532019) theme.

[image: xubuntu]

Also you may want to go to the `chrome://settings/` -> `Use GTK+ theme`

Comment: Can you describe in details how to make it work ??? On which system setting it works??? Thanks in advence.

Comment: System is Xubunty, just install theme.

Comment: Which version of Dorian-Theme. I assume that change took place in Settings -> Appereance -> Style, still no efect on my machine on 2 different Dorian-Theme.

Comment: @SkorpEN How do you install theme? By copying folder or by using PPA?

Comment: I copied folder. To me the tricky part was that after instalation I has to click in chrome://settings/ ->"Use GTK+ theme". That work for me. That part was missing in anwser.

Comment: AMAZING! Thank you! (I'm using the [*Vivacious Colors GTK Theme*](http://www.ravefinity.com/p/vivacious-colors-gtk-theme.html)).

Comment: In Chrome 69 on Linux the theme color doesn't seem to affect the address bar color.

Comment: @pts Noticed this too. Using Dorian-3.14-master and chrome version 69.0.3497.100

Comment: Please vote for this issue https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=691336#c_ts1517081156