# How to get back my previous omnibox in Google Chrome 69 or Chromium 69?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

For several versions in recent past, the color of the omnibox in Google Chrome (and Chromium) was determined by the user's gtk3 theme (if the user opted for using a gtk theme instead of classic mode in `chrome://settings`.

[image: chrome://settings]

This held true until the release of version 69 in which the omnibox now looks like this:

[image: omnibox default]

How can I restore the omnibox to its previous appearance in Google Chrome 68 that looks like this?

[image: previous omnibox appearance]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**See update at the bottom of this answer**

**Edit:** the workaround described below was limited to version 69 and 70. It is not possible to circumvent the white background of the address bar in version 71.

<s>**Further edit:** [the relevant bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=863230#c28) has now been taken up by a Googler who worked extensively on the transition of Chrome to gtk3 and so I'm hopeful of a solution soon.</s>

---

Enter `chrome://flags/#top-chrome-md` in the omnibox and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Click on the dropdown in the first entry, choose "Normal" and restart the browser.

It will change appearance from *default*

[image: default]

to *normal*

[image: normal]

Note that `flags` may disappear at any time in the future. However, a bug, [GTK+ theme ignored in omnibar in the new interface](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=863230) has been filed and, if addressed, may provide a solution without resorting to `chrome://flags`.

<s>Update: This bug has not attracted sufficient interest and currently, 20181205, nobody is assigned to it. And the workaround fails in Chrome 71.</s>

### Update 20190315:

With Chrome 73, one can use `--enable-features=WebUIDarkMode --force-dark-mode` after making sure that the Classic theme option is chosen in *Settings > Appearance* instead of GTK+. Launched in this way, Google Chrome uses a built-in dark mode that doesn't rely on or use your GTK theme colors. As of now, dropdowns such as that of bookmark folders or the ☰ icon also reflect the dark mode.

[image: Chrome 73 --- dark mode]

Comment: Thank you for your solution but it makes Chrome ugly. I hope Chrome developers fix this asap