# Ubuntu 16.04 and Chrome address bar highlight color

Tags: 16.04, unity, google-chrome, themes, colors

The autocomplete suggestions of Google's Chrome address bar has very low contrast. I hardly notice it like the screenshot:
[image]

Is there any way that allows me to set the highlight background color to more contrasted color?

Comment: Please see my revised answer. That will allow you to keep your current theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you're seeing this low contrast is because of a change to Google Chrome's user interface (UI) that took place in version 69. Certain aspects of the UI no longer obey the user's gtk theme. A bug has been filed in this regard and one can star [GTK+ theme ignored in omnibar in the new interface](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=863230).

There is a workaround, for now, described in [How to get back my previous omnibox in Google Chrome 69 or Chromium 69?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1072234/how-to-get-back-my-previous-omnibox-in-google-chrome-69-or-chromium-69).

You can solve the contrast issue described in your question by applying the workaround described in the Ask Ubuntu link above.

The image below uses the "default" mode which is the new mode present in version 69. Note the somewhat rounded tab corners and the low contrast for entries in the dropdown:

[image: Default mode]

The next image uses the "normal" mode which retains the tab design of version 68 (and earlier) and also provides better visual contrast for the selected item in the dropdown just as you would expect from your current gtk theme:

[image: Normal mode]

Both images were taken with the Adwaita theme and Google Chrome Version 69.0.3497.92 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Comment: Wonderful, thank you for help. by the way, yesterday, I have just turned to Ubuntu [tag:18.04], and the issue still the same with Chrome, until I have applied the solution that you have regarded.